# Excel2010 VBA: Get all comments of row

Tags: vba, excel-2010

is there any chance getting all comments of a single row as an array?
So, all I wanna have is a handy way to display all comments in a message box like this:

```
Dim cmt As Comment
For Each cmt In ActiveSheet.Comments
    MsgBox cmt.Text, vbOKOnly
Next cmt
```

But I cannot find any hint how to do about a single row. :(

THX :)

Comment: all comments in one MsgBox or each comment in each separate MsgBox?

Comment: no, one message box for each comment. but don't mind about the message box. The interesting part is how to get all comments of a single row.

Comment: so, see the answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very, very close...

If you want to display all comments in separate `MsgBox(es)` (here in the code below- for row no. 6) you can do it in this way:

```
Sub test()
Dim cmt As Comment
For Each cmt In ActiveSheet.Comments
    'check row in this way...- using if statement-:
    If cmt.Parent.Row = 6 Then
        MsgBox cmt.Text, vbOKOnly
    End If
Next cmt
End Sub
```

Comment: Well yes, that is actually what I am going to do about my problem. I cannot find any clue how to get a complete set of all comments of a row directly without using an if-statement. :(
Thank you anyway. :)